# Не срабатывает AFTER UPDATE триггер Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, update, триггер

Добрый день.
В базе создал таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Tabel"
(
  "UserHash" bytea NOT NULL,
  "Date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  day numeric[],
  "TotalTime" numeric
)
```

Регистрирую триггер:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tabel_trigger_func() RETURNS trigger AS $TRIGGER$ 
BEGIN 
NEW."TotalTime" = (SELECT sum(f) from "Tabel",unnest("Tabel".day) f WHERE ("UserHash" = NEW."UserHash" ) and ("Date" = NEW."Date"));
return NEW; 
END; 
$TRIGGER$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

CREATE TRIGGER tabel_trigger 
AFTER UPDATE ON "Tabel" FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tabel_trigger_func();
```

При обновлении поля таблицы, а точнее - массива "day" должно происходить автоматическое обновление поля "TotalTime"(подсчитываться сумма массива "day").
Но при обновлении ничего не происходит.

Код вставки:

```
INSERT INTO public."Tabel"(
            "UserHash", "Date", day, "TotalTime")
    VALUES ('4', '2016.11.01 00:00:00', '{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}', '0');
```

Код обновления:

```
UPDATE "Tabel"
   SET day[1] = '20' WHERE "UserHash"= '4';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменение `NEW` в триггере `AFTER UPDATE`, разумеется, сохранено не будет.  Этот же триггер после обновления вызывается. Предлагаете после триггера ещё раз сохранять строку? А ещё раз триггер вызывать надо? Вероятно, вы хотели сделать `BEFORE UPDATE`.

Если по `UserHash` + `Date` уникальный индекс, то и табличку вычитывать не надо, можно упростить триггер:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tabel_trigger_func() RETURNS trigger AS $TRIGGER$ 
BEGIN 
    NEW."TotalTime" = (SELECT sum(f) from unnest(NEW.day) f);
    return NEW; 
END; 
$TRIGGER$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tabel_trigger 
BEFORE UPDATE ON "Tabel" FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tabel_trigger_func();
```